# Showing "Kernel Dead" while comparing two string sequences of huge dataset in Python

Tags: python, string, data-structures, bioinformatics

I wrote a script to compare Human and Mouse genome sequences for 3,641,094 strings. That means it requires 1,820,547 iterations. The code below works perfectly for ~999,999 character strings, but it results in a dead Jupyter kernel when the number of strings increases to ~9,999,999 (7 digits). I wrote a function to compare the strings and put a `\n` if:

1. at least one string is lowercase or,
2. they are not similar or,
3. they are not one of the letters `['A','T','C','G']` (N,X,Y,....) these should not be counted as similar.
4. at least one of them is '-'. Otherwise, we can append the letters in the result.

For example:

```py
str1="ATCxGCGCGCGAcTTAATCGatcg----NXWQnxwq"
str2="aTCxGCGCGCGAcTTAatcgatcg--atNXWQnxwq"
```

Output:

```py
Letters similar in strings 1 and 2:
TC
GCGCGCGA
TTA
```

Here is my code:

```py
import re
def compare_strings(df, column, j):
    str1 = df["Genome Sequence"][j] #even rows
    str2 = df["Genome Sequence"][j+1] #odd rows

    #then creating a new variable to store the result after  
    #comparing the strings. You note that I added result2 because 
    #if string 2 is longer than string 1 then you have extra characters 
    #in result 2, if string 1 is  longer then the result you want to take 
    #a look at is result 2

    result1 = ''
    result2 = ''

    #handle the case where one string is longer than the other
    maxlen=len(str2) if len(str1)<len(str2) else len(str1)

    #loop through the characters
    for i in range(maxlen):
        #use a slice rather than index in case one string longer than other
        letter1=str1[i:i+1]
        letter2=str2[i:i+1]
        #create string with differences
        if (letter1.islower() and letter2.islower() and letter1==letter2):
            result1+='\n'
            result2+='\n'
        if ((letter1 not in ['A','T','C','G']) and (letter2 not in ['A','T','C','G']) and letter1==letter2):
            result1+='\n'
            result2+='\n'
        if ((letter1 == letter2) and letter1.isupper() and letter2.isupper() and (letter1!='-') and (letter2!='-') and 
            letter1 in ['A','T','C','G'] and letter2 in ['A','T','C','G']):
            result1+=letter1
            result2+=letter2
    #   if ((letter1 == letter2) and (letter1!='-') and (letter2!='-') and 
    #       letter1 in ['A','T','C','G'] and letter2 in ['A','T','C','G']):
    #       result1+=letter1
    #       result2+=letter2
        if ((letter1 != letter2) or (letter1=='-') or (letter2=='-')):
            result1+='\n'
            result2+='\n'
    #print out result
    #print ("Letters different in string 1:",result1)
    #print ("Letters different in string 2:",result2)
    word=re.sub(r'\n+', '\n', result1).strip()
    return word


#print(compare_strings(lines_frame, "Genome Sequence", 0))
comparisons = ""
for i in range(int(len(lines_frame)/2)):
    if i%2==0:
        comparisons+=(compare_strings(lines_frame, "Genome Sequence", i))
```

Could you help me to solve this Kernel Dead error on Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: This looks to me like a simple out-of-memory condition at first glance.

Comment: Do you really _need_ to store the whole result in-memory?

Comment: Is there any problem with the string variable 'comparison' or the string comparison process? @CharlesDuffy

Comment: I'd need to reproduce the failure in a condition where I could inspect the point of failure to say with _certainty_ where the problem is hit. Easiest way to get that information would be to take this out of Jupyter Notebook and run it with Python on the command line; you _should_ get an exception noting the point of failure with a stack trace (and including such an exception in its text would make this question easier to conclusively answer)

Comment: ...that said, Python strings in general are not well-suited to being mutated in-place, particularly when storing huge amounts of data. A memory-mapped disk buffer, f/e, will let the OS discard blocks from memory when memory runs short (and load them back in on-demand); see https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html

Comment: One could put the strings each into their own file, and then read one character at a time from each with `fh.read(1)` and break out of the loop when one file has no more to read. Kind of borrowing from the ole C getchar approach...

Comment: @CharlesDuffy No, I don't need to store the whole result in the memory. Rather I need to calculate the length of each similar sequences.